# How to launch a Common Lisp GTK app from a command line script (or cron)?

Tags: bash, shell, common-lisp, gtk3, sbcl

I have written a program generating a simple tray icon using cl-cffi-gtk and Common Lisp called *tray-icon.lisp* which is defined in a ASDF system called *hourly-player*. My problem is now that while this app starts fine from the command line, starting it from a script turns out to be a bit more difficult.
If I try

```
sbcl --eval '(asdf:load-system "hourly-player")' --eval '(hourly-player:run)'
```

my application is correctly loaded into the SBCL REPL and the tray icon displays correctly. However if I add a `&` to launch my script in the background it seems to immediately terminate.

Adding a `(loop)` at the end of my `run` function keeps the script from terminating but obviously also occupies my CPU a lot more than would be necessary for such a app (roughly 12% load according to conky compared to basically nothing when running in sbcl).

Is there some canonical way to keep my script alive as a background process?

I'm also aware that there are other ways of executing a lisp programm but they either share the same problem (e.g. core dumps) or seem to break my system definitions dependencies (at least buildapp and cl-launch seem to do so).

If it helps, my project can be found [here](https://github.com/dasBente/hourly-player/tree/gtk-tray-icon).

Comment: Hello, letting you know that I'd love a little blog post explaining the basic structure of a lispy Gtk application :) (to post on reddit for exple)

Comment: Sounds interesting but I don't have all that much experience with Gtk yet so I'm not sure whether I can be of any help in this regard. As far as I can tell `cl-cffi-gtk` which I have used for my project here seems to be pretty straightforward as I could clobber together my app with just the basic tutorial outline and reading through some of the documentation, at least until I ran into the problem I described here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick shot might be to do `(loop (sleep 60))` to keep your main program alive.  You also might want to look at using `within-main-loop-and-wait` instead of `within-main-loop` (from gtk+).

Comment: Wow, I somehow didn't even consider using `sleep`. I'll definitely look into using `within-main-loop-and-wait` too. I basically just startet to learn GTK in order to gain some more experience with Lisp but not getting my program to run outside of the REPL was driving me mad. I guess I got a bit too far ahead of myself. Anyway, thanks alot.